# Linux Filesystem security (Documents -> pdf)

Tags: linux, security, filesystems

I wanted to ask how I find novelties and standards for the Linux file system. (In the area of security)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of documents on Internet.

For example, you can read the CIS Benchmarks : https://www.cisecurity.org/resources/?type=benchmark. For Red Hat Linux : https://www.cisecurity.org/benchmark/red_hat_linux/ (*need a free subscription, but you will got this kind of guide (old one) : [https://web.stanford.edu/~akkornel/CIS_debian8/CIS_Debian_Linux_8_Benchmark_v1.0.0.pdf](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eakkornel/CIS_debian8/CIS_Debian_Linux_8_Benchmark_v1.0.0.pdf)*)

I like also the french document (from French ANSSI) about Linux hardening: https://www.ssi.gouv.fr/uploads/2019/03/linux_configuration-en-v1.2.pdf.

You have also some free tools to check your configuration regarding security concerns like Openscap (https://www.open-scap.org/tools/), linenum (https://github.com/rebootuser/LinEnum), etc.